# phpunit with psr-4 autoload needs manual "require" statement

Tags: phpunit

I'm following the EmailTest example at https://phpunit.de/getting-started/phpunit-9.html. It works fine.

As I change the autoload from `classmap` to `psr-4`, I found that I needed to manually add this `require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';` to make my tests work. Without it, I got `Class 'App\Email' not found` error.

My question is why the original example using `classmap` does not need that `require` line.

My codes are as follows.

`composer.json`

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src"
        }
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9"
    }
}
```

`tests/EmailTest.php`

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

use App\Email;

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

final class EmailTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testCanBeCreatedFromValidEmailAddress(): void
    {
        $this->assertInstanceOf(
            Email::class,
            Email::fromString('user@example.com')
        );
    }

    public function testCannotBeCreatedFromInvalidEmailAddress(): void
    {
        $this->expectException(InvalidArgumentException::class);

        Email::fromString('invalid');
    }

    public function testCanBeUsedAsString(): void
    {
        $this->assertEquals(
            'user@example.com',
            Email::fromString('user@example.com')
        );
    }
}
```

`src/Email.php`

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App;

final class Email
{
    private $email;

    private function __construct(string $email)
    {
        $this->ensureIsValidEmail($email);

        $this->email = $email;
    }

    public static function fromString(string $email): self
    {
        return new self($email);
    }

    public function __toString(): string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    private function ensureIsValidEmail(string $email): void
    {
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
                sprintf(
                    '"%s" is not a valid email address',
                    $email
                )
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `Email` and `EmailTest` classes in the example you refer to are not namespaced.

Comment: I thought even for classes without namespace, we still need to add "require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';". Do you mean that for classes without namespace, we don't need to do it?

Comment: I think the "require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php'" is not needed in the test cases. Because phpunit already runs it behind the scene.

Comment: I do need to run "composer dump-autoload" sometimes

Answer (score 0):

I realised that `psr-4` does not actually need this `require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';`. Because `phpunit` already does it behind the scene.

How I fixed the issue is I run `composer dump-autoload`. I thought I did not need to do it for `psr-4`. But anyway I fixed the issue.